# Showing 5 random images, but everytime 2 the same images

Tags: random, uiimageview

I'm developing a game, but I don't know how to proceed. I'm showing an image and after 5 sec it disappears and then 4 images pop up. 3 different images and 1 image that was the image that disappeared. 
I don't want to show the same images everytime, so I want random images to be shown everytime you start the application. But how can I make sure that the image that disappears, also is shown in the other 4 images? 
And is it possible to change the places of the 4 images everytime?

I hope someone will/can help me! 
Thanks!!

Comment: Choose 4 random images first, and then choose one random image out of the four that is presented first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like :

1. name your images like image0.png, .. image4.png etc..
2. create a random no using ->
      NSInteger randomNumber = arc4random() % 5;
   Which will generate no.s form 0 to 4.

3.now use something like image%@ where %@ would be the randomly generated number.

Mind you this is pretty basic solution. there could be better solutions out there.